# Как запретить скролить контент вверх

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

как можно закрепить view чтобы его нельзя было скролить вверх. Но вниз скролить чтобы можно было?
Заранее спасибо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Опишите пожалуйста проблему более детально.

Comment: Я добавил изображение, видите я скролю вью вниз и тем самым появляется пустое пространство

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Пропишите вашему `UIScrollView` делегата. Можно делегатом сделать `UIViewController` в котором находится ваш `UIScrollView`
2. Реализуйте метод делегата `func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)`

Необходимо проверять `scrollView.contentOffset.y` если он меньше нуля, то в ручную делать его равным нулю.

Пример

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scrollView.delegate = self
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 {
        scrollView.contentOffset.y = 0
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Это как раз то что мне нужно, спасибо!